# how to update like button for every post in table view cell on server

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to make an app like Instagram. I have parsed json in newsfeed table and their is 1 like button in each cell. When this like button is pressed then it should update the LIKEPOST json that I have and increment the like by 1. The problem I am getting is in updating the like button to like the post for each cell.

I am attaching the code.

This is the function for like button when pressed.

```
@IBAction func likeBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if !pressed {
        let image = UIImage(named: "Like-1.png") as UIImage!
        likeBtn.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        pressed = true
    } else
    {
        let image = UIImage(named: "liked.png") as UIImage!
        likeBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.15, y: 0.15)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                       delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
                       options: .allowUserInteraction,
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                        self?.likeBtn.transform = .identity
            },
                       completion: nil)
        likeBtn.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        pressed = false
        likeUpdateServer()

    }

 }
```

This is the function for updating the like :

```
func likeUpdateServer()
{
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let value  = userDefaults.string(forKey: "api_token")
    let api_token : String! = value
    let post_id = "9231"
    print(api_token)
    print(post_id)


    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(URL_BASE)\(LIKEPOST)")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "api_token=\(api_token!)&&post_id=\(post_id)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            print("cant run")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")



        }
        else {
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
        }
    }
}
```

This is my cellForRowAt function :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : PostDataTableViewCell = self.feedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contentViewReuse") as! PostDataTableViewCell
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    print(post)
    cell.configureCell(post : post)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: post_id value is nil .

Comment: What does this statement print on console: print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")

Comment: actually its not getting called.. LikeUpdateServer() is getting called and is printing the post id and api token but is not calling the request and task.

Comment: Please add print(postString) after let postString = "api_token=\(api_token!)&&post_id=\(post_id)" and see what it prints?

Comment: yEs it is printing the right parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your request parameters are right then after your making a dataTask then you need to resume it, so at the end of the `likeUpdateServer` method you should add this line

```
task.resume()
```

> After you create the task, you must start it by calling its 
>   `resume()` method.

You can find the indexpath of the cell by using the following code.

```
let point : CGPoint = sender.convert(.zero, tableView)
let indexPath = tableView!.indexPathForItem(at: point)
```

Add this code in your button click method and using the indexPath you can find the postId.

Also, You should flag the liked cells (I hope it will return from the server) Once you liked a cell you can update it in local post model.

Comment: it worked bro. thanks :) can u also tell me how can i update the post_id according to the table cell ? because every cell has a unique post with unique post id . how can i pass that post id in my likeUpdateServer function .. Currently i am using just a constant post id

Comment: @KeshuRai Since your original problem is solved, please ask a new question , I will help you there and others can help you there also, thanks, hope you understand, and for a rough idea you can put tag to like button in each cell as indexPath.row, which will help you which button belongs to which row , hope it helps

Comment: umm .. actually stackoverflow wont let me ask another question within 24 hrs .. anways thanks for the help :) :)

Comment: @KeshuRai I have updated the answer let me know if it helps :)

Comment: let point : CGPoint = sender.convert(.zero, tableView)
let indexPath = tableView!.indexPathForItem(at: point)

Comment: @FebinFathah thanks ,I havent tried it but I have approved the edit, hope it helps OP,

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want to do.

Every time a user clicks a button, you want to execute a JSON request and update a button.

If so, you’ll have to make an array or a dictionary and store on/off values in it. In the likeBtnPressed function, check for tableView cells indexPath.row and update a value in that “on/off” array at that index.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you mistake reduce cell of Tableview. Therefore, It repeat button like in cell other. You set true or false in function cellForRow of cell. You check true or false. If true, You show button like or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, make an array or a dictionary to store, if tableView buttons are turned on at the top of your viewController code:

`var buttonStates = [Bool]()`

In the viewDidLoad, fill the array with proper values. You can also make JSON requests to get likes from a server

```
for i in 0..<numberOfPosts {
   buttonStates.append(false)
   //in my case, all buttons are off, but be sure to implement your own logic here
}
```

In the likeBtnPressed function, find the indexPath. The simplest way is to try this:

`print(sender.superview?.superview)`

If this doesn’t work, simply add more

`print(sender.superview?.superview?.superview)`

Once print() outputs your tableViewCell class in the debuger, save it in a constant

`let cell = ...`

Then check for indexPath and change button state in the likeBtnPresses action

```
if let cellWithClass = cell as? MyClass {
   if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cellWithClass) {
      //change button state and make JSON requests here
      buttonStates[indexPath.row] = !buttonStates[indexPath.row]
   }
}
```

I suggest that you then reload the tableView

`tableView.reloadData()`

In the cellForRowAt, check, if the button is on or off

```
if buttonStates[indexPath.row] {
   //on
} else {
   /off
}
```

That should work, as far as I know (and replying from a phone )